# Hide mp3 from source code

Tags: mediaelement.js

I run a music blog at http://www.lowerfrequencies.com/ and I love mediaelements for streaming the mp3s I post. In the source for one of my posts, you will see something like this:

```
audio id="wp_mep_1" controls="controls" src="http://www.lowerfrequencies.com/wp-
content/uploads/2012/mp3s/08%20November%20Skies%20feat.%20Nina%20Kinert.mp3"
preload="none" class="mejs-player " data-mejsoptions='{"features":
["playpause","current","progress","duration","volume","tracks","fullscreen"],
"audioWidth":400,"audioHeight":30}'>
```

As yo ucan see, the link to the mp3 is viewable and anyone could go ahead and download it. What I would like, is for the mp3 to be hidden so that even if they look in the source code, they wont be able to find it. Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. At some point, the browser will need to fetch the MP3 file that you are offering. Users can use the debug features of their browser, or use an intermediate proxy, to intercept the MP3 data.

You can make it harder, but never impossible.

Comment: How do you make it harder? Maybe just remove it from the direct source code of the html.